# how do i set up a material so that im able to set up the falloff of an volumetric object from its surface?

Tags: materials, scripting, geometry-nodes, volumetrics, texture-coordinates

[image]

how do i  set up a material so that im able to set up the falloff of an volumetric object from its surface? i basically want the density at the center of the object to be normal while i can make the outside fade into a lower the density, like a gradient. like this ball but on a different object.

Comment: Hello, is it not what the Principled Volume is supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

That is what *Volume Absorption* (or *Principled Volume*) are supposed to do in Cycles (in Eevee you can use the *Mesh to Volume* system):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the spherical shape it can be done with *Spherical* gradient (3D texture).

---

Similar like here I used *Linear* gradient just to make it easier visible the effect (make it more solid at right side).

[image]
[image]

For more complex shades you would need to somehow calculate distance from surface ... that I'm not sure if possible now.

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert the mesh to volume in geometry nodes and use a principled volume shader:

[image]